# How to select and sort XML on repeating child node in PHP

Tags: php, xml, sorting

I have an XML file of data about paintings.
Each painting can belong to one or more galleries.
I need to be able to select paintings by gallery, and then sort that list into position order.
So, for example, I have XML as follows:

```
<Paintings>
  <Painting>
    <Title>Painting 1</Title>
    <Description>ABC</Description>
    <Galleries>
      <Gallery id="01">1</Gallery>
      <Gallery id="02">3</Gallery>
    </Galleries>
    <Picturefile>painting1</Picturefile>
  </Painting>
  <Painting>
    <Title>Painting 2</Title>
    <Description>DEF</Description>
    <Galleries>
      <Gallery id="02">2</Gallery>
      <Gallery id="03">2</Gallery>
    </Galleries>
    <Picturefile>painting2</Picturefile>
  </Painting>
  <Painting>
    <Title>Painting 3</Title>
    <Description>GHI</Description>
    <Galleries>
      <Gallery id="01">2</Gallery>
      <Gallery id="03">1</Gallery>
    </Galleries>
    <Picturefile>painting3</Picturefile>
  </Painting>
  <Painting>
    <Title>Painting 4</Title>
    <Description>JKL</Description>
    <Galleries>
      <Gallery id="02">1</Gallery>
      <Gallery id="03">3</Gallery>
    </Galleries>
    <Picturefile>painting4</Picturefile>
  </Painting>
</Paintings>
```

As an example, I need to select paintings in gallery "02" and then sort them into position order.
In the above xml, the node value represnts the sort order for that gallery.
For the select, I would use:

```
$gallerypics = ($paintings->xpath("Painting/Galleries/Gallery[@id='$galleryid']"));
```

It's at this point I'm stuck.  How do I then sort $gallerypics on the node value for that specific gallery?
I have the option of making the sort order an attribute rather than a value, but I'm still stuck on how to sort that.
If there was only one Gallery node per painting, this is a no brainer.  I'm stuck on how to do this with multiple Gallery nodes.  Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic idea is just to select the paintings you're after, dump them into an array, and [sort](http://php.net/usort) it based on your criteria.

---

#### Example:

```
//$xml = your xml string
$galleryid = '02';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$paintings = iterator_to_array($xpath->query("/Paintings/Painting[Galleries/Gallery/@id='$galleryid']"));
usort(
    $paintings,
    function ($a, $b) use ($xpath, $galleryid) {
        $query = "number(Galleries/Gallery[@id='$galleryid'])";
        return $xpath->evaluate($query, $a) - $xpath->evaluate($query, $b);
    }
);

foreach ($paintings as $painting) {
    echo $xpath->evaluate('string(Title)', $painting), "\n";
}
```

---

#### Output:

```
Painting 4
Painting 2
Painting 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've spent some time trying to work with this and grasp it, but am admittedly struggling to understand it.  I used what was here as is, with the only exception being I changed from loadXML to load, to load my xml file to $dom.  I get an error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /public_html/web/doc.html on line 39", pointing to the line "function ($a, $b) use ($xpath, $galleryid) {".  I've been trying to figure out the resolution, but am at a loss.

Comment: No typos.  You are 100% correct about the version of PHP.  I'm developing this site as a subdomain until it's done.  I forgot (my stupidity) that the "parent" site is still running an old version of PHP (I haven't gotten around to updating that one).  I forced the subdomain to run PHP5.5 and it works great.  Thanks very much!